# Is submerged composting of meat practical?

Tags: compost

The list of no-no composting is

- Meat
- Fish
- Poultry
- Cheese
- Oily foods
- Butter
- Dairy products
- Other animal products

Can I drop them inside water for being composted and yet feel safe from smell and rats?

Does aqua-composting as good as dry composting?

Comment: As a child i noticed dead fish stink a lot more when they are half-submerged on the bank than when they are fully on land dry rotting... You can periodically add small amounts of meat/dairy to regular compost, especially if it has worms.

Comment: @dandavis, you need to change their waters sometimes.